# Exploding LineString into segments using Shapely

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, linestring, explode

I am trying to find `explode lines` tool in [QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/explodelines.html) equivalent in `shapely` or `geopandas` (which uses `shapely` anyway). does anyone know this?

note that `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode()` does not work because it converts `multilinestring` into `linestring` which is not the issue.

Suppose I have a `LineString`:

```py
'LINESTRING ((0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4))'
```

How do I explode this into

```py
'LINESTRING ((0,0),(0,1))'
'LINESTRING ((0,1),(0,2))'
'LINESTRING ((0,2),(0,3))'
'LINESTRING ((0,3),(0,4))'
```

Comment: Did you try the [`explode()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode) method in GeoPandas?

Comment: Hi @Taras, yes I did and it did not yield the result. ```explode``` split ```multilinestring``` into ```linestring``` parts different from Qgis'. This is not the issue. The issue is I have a ```linestring``` (not a ```multilinestring```) that consists of more than 2 coordinates, and would like to convert it into multiple ```linestring``` that consists ONLY two coordinates that comprises the initial ```linestring```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
line = LineString(((0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)))
print(list(line.coords))
[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 2.0), (0.0, 3.0), (0.0, 4.0)]
for pt1,pt2 in zip(line.coords, line.coords[1:]):
    print(LineString([pt1,pt2]))

LINESTRING (0 0, 0 1)
LINESTRING (0 1, 0 2)
LINESTRING (0 2, 0 3)
LINESTRING (0 3, 0 4)
```

Or

```
def pair(list):
   '''Iterate over pairs in a list '''
   for i in range(1, len(list)):
          yield list[i-1], list[i]

for pt1,pt2 in pair(line.coords):
     print(LineString([pt1,pt2]))

LINESTRING (0 0, 0 1)
LINESTRING (0 1, 0 2)
LINESTRING (0 2, 0 3)
LINESTRING (0 3, 0 4)
```

Comment: Coordinates slices is a new feature since the version 1.2.14.

Comment: Slicing is a characteristic of Python lists (line.coords) and has nothing to do with shapely

Comment: yes and no, check this https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#points typical when using `.coords[:]`

Comment: You can use `for pt1,pt2 in zip(list(line.coords), list(line.coords)[1:]):`

Comment: the first code works so well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit lame but working solution which includes the Python's [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) class with the [`rotate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) method

```py
from collections import deque
from shapely.geometry import LineString

line = LineString(((0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)))

vertices1 = [(x, y) for x, y in line.coords]

vertices2 = deque(vertices1)
vertices2.rotate(-1)
vertices2 = list(vertices2)

line_as_parts_enclosed = [LineString([vertices1[i], vertices2[i]]).wkt for i in range(len(vertices1))]
print(line_as_parts_enclosed)
# ['LINESTRING (0 0, 0 1)', 'LINESTRING (0 1, 0 2)', 'LINESTRING (0 2, 0 3)', 'LINESTRING (0 3, 0 4)', 'LINESTRING (0 4, 0 0)']


line_as_parts_opened = [LineString([vertices1[i], vertices2[i]]).wkt for i in range(len(vertices1)-1)]
print(line_as_parts_opened)
# ['LINESTRING (0 0, 0 1)', 'LINESTRING (0 1, 0 2)', 'LINESTRING (0 2, 0 3)', 'LINESTRING (0 3, 0 4)']
```